# yandex-tank. Ошибка с отключением phantom

Tags: яндекс-танк

Собираюсь подавать нагрузку танком через jmeter. 
Согласно мануалу в load.ini:

```
[tank]
; Disable phantom:
plugin_phantom=
; Enable JMeter instead:
plugin_jmeter=yandextank.plugins.JMeter
[jmeter]
jmx=/home/Test.jmx
```

Запускаю sudo yandex-tank -c load.ini
Итог:

```
[WARNING] /etc/yandex-tank is not accessible to get configs list
[ERROR] Exception: Validation error:
phantom:
  address: [required field]
  load_profile: [required field]
```

Правильно ли я понимаю что фантом не отключился и требует параметров? Как корректно его отключить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать YAML-формат конфига:

```
phantom:
  enabled: false
```

подробнее: http://yandextank.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#autostop

также при запуске в папке теста должен был сохраниться *pre-validation-config.yaml - это ваш конфиг, сконвертированный в YAML. Таким образом, вам не придется переписывать весь конфиг, а только исправить этот.